# What stats method to apply when measuring a trait multiple times from the same individual?

Tags: independence

I have 2 species of wildflowers. 
Using scanning electron microscopy. 
I took images of the petal surface.
On the petal surface I measured the height and width of individual cells. I have 1 to 3 individuals per species. 
I want to compare these measurements between species
Are the measurements of cells independent or do I need to use a statistical test to account for the lack of independence? If so, what tests should I consider?

Comment: What is the goal of the analysis?  Are you interested in determining if they are different, or is this purely exploratory?

Comment: I observed that there are sometimes conical cells on the surface of the petals. I wanted to see if there was any significant differences between the height of the cells between two closely related plant species.

Comment: There is very likely correlation within an individual plant.  Try a mixed effects model, where the random effect is the individual and the fixed effect is species.  Can you post some a little data to help us cement the problem in our minds?

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on the nature of your question, but I should think that height and width of cells are going to be highly correlated and both are measures of cell size. I would probably just multiply height by width to get a better approximation for cell area/size, Alternatively you could run a PCA analysis.

Comment: I mainly want to compare the heights of the cells between species. But I do not not have many plants. I made multiple measurements on the same plant. Is there any way to compare?